# i'm trying to hide one text on hover and display another in it's place using only html & css

Tags: html

i want someone to hover over 'plays' and see 'prose' while 'plays' temporarily disappears.

But this is what it looks like
[image: picture of my problem]
The word plays remains in the background upon hover

```css
.prose {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.prose a {
  visibility: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.plays-title:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: cell;
}

.title:hover .prose {
  visibility: visible;
}

.title:hover .prose a {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title" style="float:right;">
  <!--on hover-->
  <span class="prose"><a href="/prose">PROSE</a></span>
  <!--hover element end-->
  <span class="plays-title"> PLAYS </span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **.plays-title** opacity to 0 when hovering **.title**

```
.title:hover .plays-title {
    opacity: 0;
}
```